# Are there any exceptions that I may have missed in this problem?

Tags: c++

Recently I've been working on this problem on SPOJ:

> Given a set of N integers A = {1, 2, 3, …, N} and an integer S, your task is find a way to insert an operator '+' or '-' to every neighbor pair of A, that the result of the expression after insert equal to S.
>
> WARNING: You can't put any operators in front of 1.
>
> Input:
>   A single line, including N and S (1 ≤ N ≤ 500, |S| ≤ 125250)
>
> Output:
>   If there are way(s) to insert, output any of them, otherwise output “Impossible” (without quotes).
>
> Example:
>
> Input:
>   9 5
>   Output:
>   1-2+3-4+5-6+7-8+9
>
> Input:
>   5 6
>   Output:
>   Impossible

I've already been messing up with these code, but SPOJ always yields that I've done this problem in the wrong way. I think there might be exceptions that I haven't found out.

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int a[501] = { };
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        a[i] = 1;
        sum += i;
    }
    int s;
    cin >> s;
    int aim = sum - s;
    if ((aim % 2 != 0) || (s < -sum + 2) || (s > sum) || (s == -sum + 4) || (s == sum - 1))
    {
        cout << "Impossible" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    int c = n;
    while (aim != 0)
    {
        if (aim >= c)
        {
            if (aim - 2 * c != 2)
            {
                aim -= (2 * c);
                a[c] = -1;
                c--;
            }
            else
            {
                a[c - 1] = -1;
                a[2] = -1;
                aim -= (2 * c + 2);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            a[aim / 2] = -1;
            aim = 0;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        if (a[i] == 1)
            if (i == 1)
                cout << i;
            else
                cout << "+" << i;
        else
            cout << "-" << i;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For example, wrong output `1+2-3` is emitted for input `3 2`.

Comment: I believe you have a typo level error in your checking for impossible cases. I haven't checked out your algorithm for assigning +'s and -'s.

Comment: BTW, There is a formula you should be able to find or figure out for the sum of the first n integers. That would let you replace the loop to calculate sum with a calculation.

Answer (score 0):

You are subtracting `2 * c` from `aim` after checking if `aim >= c`.

Changing the check to `aim >= 2 * c` will improve your program.